# Ansible - Replace specific XML tag with jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to replace a specific tag of the jenkins config.xml with ansible. The file looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy$Unsecured"/>
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.SecurityRealm$None"/>
  <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
  ...
</hudson>
```

The content of the replacement is an jinja template and should replace the tag `<securityRealm .../>` and even if the equivalent form exists `<securityRealm>...</<securityRealm>`

---

Edit: For a detailed explanation of what I want to do.

I have a jinja template that represents a piece of the XML configuration. Let's say that is the template:

```
<securityRealm class="hudson.security.SecurityRealm$Specific"/>
  <customTag1>{{ valueOne }}</customTag1>
  <customTag2>{{ valueTwo }}</customTag2>
</securityRealm>
```

So the final result looks as follows.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy$Unsecured"/>
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.SecurityRealm$Specific"/>
    <customTag1>anyConfig</customTag1>
    <customTag2>anotherValue</customTag2>
  </securityRealm>
  <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
  ...
</hudson>
```

Comment: There is a module called lineinfile to replace. Alternatively, you can call a sed command using shell module.

Comment: There is a 3rd party module for XML manipulation: https://github.com/cmprescott/ansible-xml

Comment: You could have used a combination of Vars & template!! Just put variable values in vars/main.yml & refer those vars in template.

Comment: @AniruddhaJawanjal You mean, I should save the whole configuration in my role as a template? But I do not want that, I only want the part of the configuration as a template, which is necessary for the assessment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not knowldgeable for xml, but I know it's a text file.  So use the jinja2 templating built into Ansible, by leveraging the `ansible.builtin.template:` module

1. Build templated config.xml.j2 with something like "{{ CustomSecurityRealm }}".

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <hudson>
   <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
   <mode>NORMAL</mode>
   <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
   <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy$Unsecured"/>
   "{{ CustomSecurityRealm }}"
   <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
   ...
   </hudson>
   ```
2. Set default var for CustomSecurityRealm to the block of text you want to use normally.
3. For any situation that needs a different config, override the variable, using group, host, or extra vars.
4. Use `ansible.builtin.template:` module to replace the config file with your new one built from your .j2 template.
5. One elegant way is to pass a variable to an included task, playbook or role.

[Detailed tips](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#tips-on-where-to-set-variables)  on setting vars and order of precedence from Ansible Docs.